# IIS Rewrite loses path in Angular application upon refresh

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, iis

So I've been struggling with my Angular.js application and IIS rewrite. I have my site sitting in http://server/jwb/ folder. I have it rewriting to the index.html file in /jwb/ and I have a  inside of the index.html. The problem is that when I navigate to http://server/jwb/parties/12345, it appears fine when done through angular, but when I hit refresh on the browser I lose the CSS and javascript. I look in the console and they are being rewritten to http://server/jwb/parties/js/nameoffile.js, etc. What I want to do is tell IIS rewrite to always see the js, css and img files where they really reside which is at http://server/jwb/js, http://server/jwb/css and http://server/jwb/img, etc.

What is the rewrite rule that will accomplish this for me? Is there a better way than using a rewrite rule?

I currently have this in my web.config:

```
<rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^index\.html" ignoreCase="false" />
        <action type="None" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

However, this still does weird things. I even did some tests with the relative paths and here is what I found:

We have now tested the following ways of referencing the files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
```

OR

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

OR

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.css" />
```

OR

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.css" />
```

And none of them work. The following shows what happens when we use each file in reference to a path for our application. For sake of argument, our paths are as follows:

```
index --> http://10.34.34.46/jbvdev/calendar
documents --> http://10.34.34.46/jbvdev/documents/BC498484
caseNotes --> http://10.34.34.46/jbvdev/casenotes/CV/LA%20/2081/BC498484
```

[image]

Comment: try adding base tag or use absolute path to resources in the page itself

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css" />` is actually an absolute path ... looking for css directory in root of site. The leading `/` tells browser to start at root or whatever base tag defines as root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue... and after doing all the adding base ref and stuff which is suggested elsewhere still had the exact the same issue.

So yes, do add a base ref "/" in you index.html or whatever page is the base for your angular app. Then you need to revert to good ol' regex...

I played for a while to get the right bits in the right places, and capturing the right parts.... so you'll need to tweek it for yours...

For me my paths were

1. /Content/blah.whatever for the html files and css and
2. /Scripts/some.js etc for my javascript

What was happening was ON REFRESH ONLY the app route was getting inserted before the /Content or /Scripts... below is the set of rules that finally fixed it for me...

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Removevesseldetailsscripts" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*[/])Scripts/(.*)$" />
      <conditions>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="Scripts/{R:2}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Removevesseldetailscontent" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*[/])Content/(.*)$" />
      <conditions>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="Content/{R:2}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The R:2 bit is to put the angular route back in the url in the right place, obviously there is R:1 as well which captured the root of the actual path...

Have a play and let me know if I can be of any more help!! Good luck!!!

Comment: This worked perfectly! I am not sure about all these other rewrite rules floating around, but this one seems bulletproof! Anyoen using this, be sure to point the action rule to where your application is truly located PLUS the index.html (or whatever the heck you call your main page).